# How to Set the theme in Fragments programmatically?

Tags: java, android

I wrote a code for setting a theme for activities **setTheme(R.style.darkTheme);** but i don't know how to write in fragments activity to set the theme.The code is for activities

```
if(sharedPref.loadNightModeState()==true)
        {
            setTheme(R.style.darkTheme);

        }
        else {
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
        }
```

This is my style.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="backgroundcolor">@color/background</item>
        <item name="textcolor">@color/textcolor</item>
        <item name="buttoncolor">@color/red</item>

    </style>
    <style name="darkTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">#212121</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#000000</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="backgroundcolor">#303030</item>
        <item name="textcolor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="buttoncolor">@color/red</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

This is my fragment code

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_state, container, false);
        sharedPref=new SharedPref(getActivity());

        if(sharedPref.loadNightModeState()==true)
        {
            setTheme(R.style.darkTheme);

        }
        else {
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
        }
        return  view;
    }
```

error is coming in this setTheme(R.style.AppTheme) line .

Comment: if you want to add theme in your fragments add this code in parent activity of your fragment it will work @sathyamurthy

Comment: You should set theme before inflating your views. If you want to set theme only for the fragment you cant wrap you context with ContextThemeWrapper and use it to get inflater.

Comment: `requireActivity().setTheme()`